# Is dialkyldimethylammonium chloride suitable for sterilization in mycology?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, alcohols

In hobby-mycology 70% rubbing alcohol is commonly used for sterilizing work surfaces, bags, syringes, still air boxes, basically everything.

Alcohol however, seems to have some downsides, when it comes to mycology as it needs a long soak time to actually kill anything and it doesn't kill mold and mold spores at all, which is one of the most common contaminants.

So I am looking for something, which does not create toxic fumes, does kill bacteria and fungi spores including mold and acts quickly.

Is dialkyldimethylammonium chloride the right solution for me? If yes, what dilution should I use? Would 2% be sufficient? Does it become denatured after 24h mixed with water like bleach? And most importantly, is it safe for use at home? Will it cause residue buildup, like bleach would?

Comment: I am not aware of any ammonium chloride desinfectant abilities. Wikipedia article does not mention it either.

Comment: What about dialkyldimethylammonium chloride? Or is that something completely different?

Comment: Yes, it is something completely different. With long alkyls, it is cation active tenside, that could serve as desinfectant.

Comment: I edited my question.